# How to put initial condition of ODE at a specific time point using odeint in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

How to put initial condition of ODE at a specific time point using odeint in Python?

So I have y(0) = 5 as initial condition,
following code works::

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function that returns dy/dt
def model(y,t):
    k = 0.3
    dydt = -k * y
    return dydt

# initial condition
y0 = 5

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,20)

# solve ODE
y = odeint(model,y0,t)

# plot results
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.show()
```

I wanna see the graph in both negative and positive time line.

So I change `t = np.linspace(0,20)` to `t = np.linspace(-5,20)`, but then the initial condition is taken as y(-5) = 5.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can, according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)

But you can solve for positive and negative `t`'s separately and then stich them together. Replace the relevant lines with

```
tp = np.linspace(0,20)
tm = np.linspace(0,-5)

# solve ODE
yp = odeint(model,y0,tp)
ym = odeint(model,y0,tm)

# stich together; note we flip the time direction with [::-1] construct
t = np.concatenate([tm[::-1],tp])
y = np.concatenate([ym[::-1],yp])
```

this produces
[image: sol]

Comment: Thanks!. But that's too bad if I can't do that, it feels inconvenient. I will wait and see if there is a better solution.

Comment: @Nor.Z Out of curiosity, what do you envision a better solution to look like?

Comment: @Reti43 Maybe there could be other function instead of odeint. Because this kind of functionality is frequently used in ode graphing.

Comment: @Nor.Z The functionality of solving before and after y0 might be frequent, but who told you this isn't how it's done under the hood? The point of numerical solutions is you start with (t0, y0) and then calculate y+dy based of that. You could have a function of the form `solve(t, y0, t0)`, and internally it'd split the independent variable to [tstart, t0] and [t0, tend] and do what piterbarg showed you.