# Python ODEs system: fixing values in middle of evaluation span

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I'm trying to solve an ODE system in Python between t = -1 and t = 1, fixing the values at t = 0.

I tried using `solve_ivp`, but it only allows you to fix the initial values (i.e. at t = -1). I haven't found a way to do this yet.

I've worked with Mathematica and NDSolve allows me to fix values in the middle of the evaluation range. Is there a way to do this in Python?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
    
        def ode(t,Ephi,g,l):
                return[2*(Ephi[0]**2)*g*np.sin(2*Ephi[1]),Ephi[0]*(l+2*g*np.cos(2*Ephi[1]))]
        
        l_value = 1
        g_value = 1
        t_min = -1
        t_max = 1
        t_ev = 1000
            
        E_0 = 1
        phi_0 = 0
        
        res = solve_ivp(ode,(t_min,t_max),(E_0,phi_0),t_eval = np.linspace(t_ev,t_max,t_ev),args = (g_value,l_value))
```

The solution given is that with `Ephi[0][t_min] = E_0`, `Ephi[1][t_min] = phi_0` but I would like to solve it for the same interval `(t_min, t_max)` while fixing `Ephi[0][t = 0] = E_0`, `Ephi[1][t = 0] = phi_0`. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Are you setting just some values at t=0, or all of them?  If all of them, then you are actually solving two [IVPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem), one of which goes backwards in time.  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide more details about the problem.

Comment: See [ask]. It's unspecific. You should choose or define a specific ODE.

Comment: The solver serves to compute states at new points from the state at the initial point. It does not matter if forwards or backwards. As an extra, the solver also produces states at intermediate values, so that one only needs solver calls for the extreme points of the intended solution interval. A rather short implementation of this idea can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974311/how-to-put-initial-condition-of-ode-at-a-specific-time-point-using-odeint-in-pyt.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thank you very much. That works as expected.

Comment: @Álvaro I think I misunderstood the question. I thought you had the states at t = -1, t = 0, and t = 1 and you wanted to solve for the solution between those times.

Comment: @jared sorry for the confusion. No, this is not such a problem, it's much easier. I have the state at t = 0 and I want to solve between t = -1 and t = 1, but I don't know the states in either of those points. As Lutz said before, this can be achieved running twice the solver, forward and backward. It's not a satisfying solution for me (i'd love to tell directly solve_ivp in which point I want to implement the conditions, just like NDSolver in Mathematica), but it works. 

Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Computing for both directions simultaneously only works in the rare case where a symbolic solution exists. In the other cases also Mathematica will need two runs of the numerical solver, as the propagation step-by-step is unidirectional. // In the hypothetical case where the state has 3 components and values for the first component are given at t=-1,0,1, the solution would require solving a generalized boundary value problem. This is essentially a non-linear system in 3 variables, where each evaluation of the system requires one or two runs of the ODE solver.